# How to find the window of a specific file in the multiple windows of Okular with multiple files open

Tags: 12.04, okular

I use Okular to open, say 5, PDF files.
Now I need to find one PDF file, say "HelloWorld.pdf"

However, when I click the Okular icon, 5 small windows show up on the desktop. The windows are so small that I can not tell which one is "HelloWorld.pdf"

I hope Okular has a "Window" button, so that when I click it, it will show 5 PDF file names, and I can easily choose one.
Or maybe I miss how to do it, since I think Okular should have a similar function as it is a famous PDF browser for Ubuntu.

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu 13.04 you can right click on the launcher in question to show a list of open windows and their titles. You should be able to identify the right instance based on its title.

Comment: Update Ubuntu? I need a thorough second thought. But than you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 or 13.04, if you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you reach the `okular` window, if you wait a second with `okular` marked you will see all the windows with their names above each preview.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! Just not very inconvenient, since I need to use Alt+Tab to find the Okular app, which is slower than I directly click the Okular icon on the menu bar. But it works, and maybe no more efficient way I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can also press one time Alt + Tab and, without stop pressing Alt key, move with arrow keys. And if this helped you, you can mark this as a helpful answer.